# MakeHuman, Sculpt Mode Grinds To A Halt

Tags: sculpt, makehuman

Version 3.3.1
I load a figure direct from Makhuman then go to sculpt mode and after a lag it goes into sculpt mode but none of the functions are usable.
Click on a function and it will hang for quiet a while before changing icons then is unusable.
I also have version 2.92.0 installed and it works fine on this version.
[image]

Comment: Disable the subdivision modifier while sculpting.

Comment: When importing a MakeHuman figure direct into Blender. You might find Blender slows down in sculpt mode. To cure this, disable the subdivision modifier while sculpting.